# Why npm packages stored via Artifactory have '-' (dash) in their path?

Tags: npm, artifactory

After setting up a remote repository for NPM and having successfully retrieved the dependencies via Artifactory, I saw that all NPM packages are stored with an intermediate dash '-' in their path, such as :

http://host:8081/artifactory/npm-remote-cache/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.7.tgz

It's also the same for the published version to a local npm repository.
Both repositories are using the npm-default layout.

No big deal there, but does anyone know why is this dash here in the middle ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

This is done in order to follow the layout used by the public [NPM registry](http://registry.npmjs.org).
For example, in the case of the package you mentioned the public URL would be - http://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.7.tgz

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't note that it was the case on the public registry.

Comment: that still doesn't really answer the question of why there is a dash in the path ;)

Comment: @dokaspar- did you find the reason? I'm trying to understand as well.